# Google Assistant needs Wi-Fi network to work? Google Pixel 6

Tags: wi-fi, google-assistant, google-pixel-6

Occasionally (not all the time), when invoking the Google Assistant on my Pixel 6 phone, I get the exact message "For that, you'll have to turn on Wi-Fi and connect to a network."

[image: see image]

Online, I have zero results for that message when searching for it, which seems plain weird. I've tried giving google assistant any permissions it might not have had out of the box, alas, the problem persists. A reboot usually does fix it though. Still, a nuisance. Cellular data is always on, and I live in San Diego.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not enabled. (dunno why, but i see cell signal but not data carrier)

- Check your APN and Cell Data settings. (it might be as simple as a switch)

Otherwise go into developer settings (tap build number 4 times)

Then set "data always on" (this is just useful to have selected)

## Troubleshooting steps: For data Connectivity

1.) There is a "data enabled" in your network settings. Its a switch, or a checkbox.

2.) APNs. If that doesnt work, find your APN settings and match them to your carrier.

- for me, I google for "T-Mobile APN settings"
- if its greyed out, try adding a new APN and manually set it up. You will be able to tick the bubble after you hit [SAVE] in the ... menu.

If that fails, then you need to flash your device to a different carrier.

(But thats a pixel, so its probably just data switch disabled. Cause even bad simcards/inactive would still show 1x/hsp*/3g/lte/4/5g etc)

Comment: Thanks, I now see what you mean. Very strange, however it appears it often shows cell reception but no speed or carrier info, see attached screenshot from just now with cell data working fine (messages coming in etc) but once again, assistant presenting me with the same error message... I DO run a firewall, netguard.

Comment: Data always on in dev options had already been set to on. Can't really find apn settings other than the default apn 'fast.t-mobile.com setting but I can't edit or make changes. I *could* add another apn, but not sure which one, or if that would help. In looking around online, 'fast.t-mobile.com' seems to be the go-to apn for pixel phones on T-mobile.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Uu5ver9